# Customize search query in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to customize my default search in magento website. In frontend, If customer enter any keyword I don't want it to search in Product Description field. Except product description, all fields are okay. But It should not look for a keyword in product description column.  How and where can I customize the SQL query which generates the search results. Please guide me on this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no need to change any SQL to do this.

1) Goto mangento Admin, Catalog -> attributes. select description.

2) Change frontend properties: set

```
Use in Quick Search     = NO
Use in Advanced Search  = NO
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry I'm new to magento. It was so simple.